# Odd file naming using wget with Nexus Rest API

Tags: java, rest, maven, wget, nexus

I have a script that pulls .war artifacts from our nexus repository using wget to pull the artifacts via the Nexus Rest API.

The url that I hit with wget is similar to this:

http://our.nexus.net:8081/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?g=com.somecompany&a=SomeArtifact&v=1.0.0&r=releases&p=war

It works fine in our dev environment, and pulls an artifact with the name `SomeArtifact-1.0.0.war`.

However, in our test environment, it pulls the artifact correctly, but gives it the name:

`redirect?g=com.somecompany&a=SomeArtifact&v=1.0.0&r=releases&p=war`

Any ideas as to why it is not renaming it correctly?

Here is an example output from wget when it names it wrong.

```
--2015-05-11 11:22:12-- http://our.nexus.net:8081/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?g=com.somecompany&a=SomeArtifact&v=1.0.0&r=releases&p=war
Resolving our.nexus.net... (IP)
Connecting to our.nexus.net|(IP)|:8081... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: http://our.nexus.net:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/releases/content/com/somecompany/SomeArtifact/1.0.0/SomeArtifact-1.0.0.war [following]
--2015-05-11 11:22:12-- http://our.nexus.net:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/releases/content/com/somecompany/SomeArtifact/1.0.0/SomeArtifact-1.0.0.war
Reusing existing connection to our.nexus.net:8081.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 22046212 (21M) [application/java-archive]
Saving to: "/tmp/deploy/redirect?g=com.somecompany&a=SomeArtifact&v=1.0.0&r=releases&p=war"

100%[======================================================>] 22,046,212 56.7M/s in 0.4s

2015-05-11 11:22:12 (56.7 MB/s) - "/tmp/deploy/redirect?g=com.somecompany&a=SomeArtifact&v=1.0.0&r=releases&p=war" saved [22046212/22046212]
```

And when it does the naming correctly:

```
--2015-05-11 11:22:12-- http://our.nexus.net:8081/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?g=com.somecompany&a=SomeArtifact&v=1.0.0&r=releases&p=war
Resolving our.nexus.net... (IP)
Connecting to our.nexus.net|(IP)|:8081... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: http://our.nexus.net:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/releases/content/com/somecompany/SomeArtifact/1.0.0/SomeArtifact-1.0.0.war [following]
--2015-05-11 11:22:12-- http://our.nexus.net:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/releases/content/com/somecompany/SomeArtifact/1.0.0/SomeArtifact-1.0.0.war
Reusing existing connection to our.nexus.net:8081.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 22046212 (21M) [application/java-archive]
Saving to: "/tmp/deploy/SomeArtifact-1.0.0.war"

100%[======================================================>] 22,046,212 56.7M/s in 0.4s

2015-05-11 11:22:12 (56.7 MB/s) - "/tmp/deploy/SomeArtifact.1.0.0.war" saved [22046212/22046212]
```

EDIT: some additional information below.

Both the dev and test environment have wget version 1.12.

The dev server, where it works is running RedHat Enterprise Linux OS version 6.4.
The test server, where it does not work is version 6.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is the difference in wget setup in RedHat Enterprise Linux OS version 6.4 versus 6.6.

I ended up just using the -O flag with wget to ensure the file name was what I wanted.

```
wget -O SomeArtifact.1.0.0.war "http://our.nexus.net:8081/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?g=com.somecompany&a=SomeArtifact&v=1.0.0&r=releases&p=war"
```